# Download single most recent post from Instagram profile using Instaloader

Tags: python, instagram, instaloader

i am trying to download the latest post of a profile using "Instaloader" in Python.
I have found something about hashtags, but not about profiles.
So how do i download only the latest post of a profile?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a section on [profiles](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.Profile).

From the examples:

```py
L = Instaloader()
profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, USERNAME)
```

You can then use the [`get_posts`](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.Profile.get_posts) method to get a profile's posts, including the latest one.